# DefaultSharedPreferences() does not clear() values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `defaultSharedPreferences()` throughout my application. I define it once in my **Application class** and use it whenever needed:

```
public class Itu extends Application {
public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    sharedPreferencesFDefault = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
}
public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferencesItu(){
    return sharedPreferencesFDefault;
}
public static int getStudentNameColor(SharedPreferences sharedPref){
    int color = sharedPref.getInt("studentNameColor", -1);
    if (color == -1) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("studentNameColor", 0);
        editor.commit();
        color = sharedPref.getInt("studentNameColor", 0);
    }
    ....
    return color;
}
```

**I use it** in this Activity:

```
public class StudentAddActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
    private void attemptAdd() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref=((Itu)getApplication()).getSharedPreferencesItu();
        int color=Itu.getStudentNameColor(sharedPref);
}
```

**Now i want to delete all values** from my another activity **which does not work**:

```
public class CourseListActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault;
    ...
    sharedPreferencesFDefault = ((Itu) getApplication()).getSharedPreferencesItu();
    sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit().clear().commit();
}
```

After i call `sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit().clear().commit();`, i still see that my `"studentNameColor"` value exists in `defaultSharedPreferences`.

What might be problem? Using defaultSharedPreferences instead of sharedPreference? or passing Application context instead of each activity's context? or i call wrong function to delete?

**UPDATE 1:** i can delete it from my Application class, but not from my Activities. why?

**UPDATE 2:** i can delete now it from another activity by accessing variable directly:

```
((Itu) getApplication()).sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit().clear().commit();
```

But if i get sharedPreference variable through my static function, i can not clear it, why?

Comment: try calling static methods like Itu.getSharedPreferencesItu();

Comment: I understood the error, but still has question in my mind, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605084/accessing-static-sharedpreference-variable-directly-vs-through-getter-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault;` to `public SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault;` and now `clear()` works. The thing was getting `static` sharedPreference, from Application class, into `static` variable of Activity class.

I still don't know what happens when we initialize `static` variable with another `static` variable. You can follow that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605084/accessing-static-sharedpreference-variable-directly-vs-through-getter-function?lq=1).