# Accessing static SharedPreference variable directly VS through Getter function

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, getter

I have static `DefaultSharedPreference` variable defined as like here:

```
public class Itu extends Application {
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        sharedPreferencesFDefault = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
    }
    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferencesItu(){
        return sharedPreferencesFDefault;
    }
}
```

**(1. way)** When i access it directly  from some Activity, it clears sharedPreference:

```
((Itu) getApplication()).sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit().clear().commit();
```

**(2. way)** But when i access  it through Getter method and try to `clear()` it, it does NOT work:

```
public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault;
sharedPreferencesFDefault = ((Itu) getApplication()).getSharedPreferencesItu();
sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit().clear().commit();
```

*Old question:* What is the difference between *1.way* and *2.way?*

**UPDATE:** I changed `public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault` to `public SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault` and both ways worked.

*New question:* What happens when i initialize `static` variable with another `static` variable indeed?

Comment: The best way is not to have it `static` and access it using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`

Comment: @StenSoft since i need to access "same" sharedPreference through multiple Activities and Fragment, i need it as static. If i get sharedPreference through different contexts, i think i'll get different sharedPreference files which i do not desire.

Comment: [It returns the same preferences for the whole application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9518308/4538344)